# export data to gridview from excel

Tags: asp.net, gridview

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AppendHeader("content.disposition", "attachment;filename=check.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
StringWriter strwriter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htmlwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwriter);
GridView2.RenderControl(htmlwriter);
Response.Write(strwriter.ToString());
Response.End();
```

I 'm trying to import data to excel all the code is executing well but nothing is happing no file is generating, please help me I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you change `content.disposition` for `content-disposition`:

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=check.xls");
```

Two additional settings are also required:

1) Event validation must be deactivated at the page level:

```
<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" ... %>
```

2) The following page function must be overridden (it can stay empty):

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
}
```

Comment: Strange, it works for me with the same code. Can you add to your question the rest of the function where this code is called?

Comment: i have a function that contains all the above code and on a button click i 'm calling this function.. is there some property or rule of grid view for generating the sheet.?

Comment: I updated my answer with two additional conditions to allow exporting the Excel file. In my test code, the button click executes only the code shown in your question (with the minor correction suggested in my answer). If it still doesn't work for you, can you try with different browsers? Does it fail for all of them?

Comment: Two more things you can check: (1) Does the postback occur when you click the button? Can you confirm that all the code lines in your question are executed? (2) Is the GridView inside an UpdatePanel? If so, you can try without it, to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: thank u actually gridview was inside the update panel, its good now

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark the answer as accepted (with the check mark) if it solved your problem.